# Scheme: API documentation generator?

Tags: scheme, documentation-generation

[Javadoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) can be used to automatically generate API documentation for Java code, using annotations in the comments above each class, method, etc.

Along those same lines, is there any tool that can generate API documentation from Scheme code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this question, I realized that SchemeDoc actually links back to this section in the Scheme FAQ, which contains a handful of tools:

[Are there any tools for documenting Scheme code?](http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-faq-misc)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the eternal answer to any answer about Scheme: yes, there are about fifty such systems.

One pointer among many: Racket's "scribble" system supports literate programming, a more aggressive form of the docstring idea. Here's a link:

http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/lp.html

There are many others.

John Clements

Comment: Can you provide links to any other such systems?

Comment: Looks like you answered your own question, yes?

Comment: Yes and no: I only found about 5 doctools. The other fifty or so must be floating around somewhere else...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could take a look at this one: [SchemeDoc](http://www.cs.aau.dk/~normark/schemedoc/)